# Is camera 1.3 version compatible with Raspberry Pi 4 B?

Tags: picamera

Is the 1.3 version of camera compatible with Raspberry Pi 4B ? I need to use it for an object detection app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Both version 1 and 2 cameras can be used on all Pi models.